# How to hide the particulars uitableViewCell webview in when i click on that particuar cells button uitableview?

Tags: ios, xcode

In tableviewcells i have a buttons and webViews, with some array count.so when i tap on particular tableViewcells button action. i have to hide that particular tables cells webview?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, In `UIButton` action, you will get cell index if you've given tag to your button, using that tag, you can make cell object with  `NSIndexPath` for the cell you've tapped, hide `UIWebView` subviews within that cell, you may need to set its height base on some condition which you've made in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` of `UITableView`. Another way to get the cell is, `[button superview];` here you'll get `containerview` for particular cell, and apply the same logic, this would only work if you've added button and webview in `contentview`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[cell.webView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Make the webView can't get the user touch focus, so that the cell will get the user interaction : )

Comment: Could you explain why this fixes the problem?

Comment: @Cristik Because the webView get the touch focus : )

Comment: Could you add this to your answer, so that the asker and further readers that stumble upon your answer could better understand why and how the line of code you provided solves the problem?